# Hibernate query shows old values

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

My problem is that using `addEntity(MyEntityObject.class)` in a query, result is not what i excpect but i see old values, the values before update operations.

My Hibernate configuration file not contains specific configurations, just the db connection, show sql property **true** (for my debugging) and all references to my **hbm** files

If i try to get data using the mapped object i get old values:

```java
List<MyEntityObject> resultSet = session.createSQLQuery("select * from table").addEntity(MyEntityObject.class).list();
```

Instead, if i try to get data just as list of objects array everything works fine:

```java
List<Object[]> resultSet = session.createSQLQuery("select * from table").list();
```

I would like to know what can be the cause of this behaviour, so what can be wrong with the first approach.

Comment: you need to show us the code

Comment: Hibernate should flush every modification to the database before a select, but this behaviour can be altered. I think that on the first case hibernate is recognizing that you are trying to load entites that are already loaded inside the persistence context, so they are not getting refreshed. On the second case hibernate always goes to the database because you are not loading any entities. Show as the update code and your transaction strategy and migth be able to tell you more

Comment: Did you commit your transaction/